# Windows Wireshark on network bridge does not show all the packets

Tags: networking, wireshark, windows-networking

I have a Windows PC with two NIC used for network monitoring between two devices.

When I setup a network bridge and launch Wireshark. I can see ARP requests and IP multicasts on both sides but **no unicast traffic** (ARP response, TCP), which I know is present from devices' logs.

Then on the same machine I launch VirtualBox Ubuntu with both adapters bridged directly to it. I bring up Linux bridge and launch Wireshark - works fine! (Well, I know Linux is better tool for networking than Windows but still...)

I verified the bridged interfaces on Windows have promiscuous mode ON using  `Get-NetAdapter |ft -Property ifAlias, PromiscuousMode`

Any tweaks than can be done to fix it?